# Single quote (') or backslash (/) is causing my program a syntax error. Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012

everything is working properly but when I entered (25's/Box) on my id textbox it prompts" *Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression "25's/Box'*. 
I know it has to be the single quote thats causing the error. How am I gonna fix it?

```
it = dgvItems.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
qt = dgvItems.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
un = Convert.ToString(dgvItems.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value)
id = Convert.ToString(dgvItems.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value)
uc = dgvItems.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
tc = dgvItems.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value


oledbSql.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Items(ResoNo, ItemNo, Qty, Unit, ItemDesc, UnitCost, TotalCost) VALUES('" _
                       & rn & "'," & it & "," & qt & ",'" & un & "','" & id & "'," & uc & "," & tc & ")"
oledbSql.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: You are inserting raw values into SQL; a SQL string needs to be `'string'`; but you get `'str'ing'` (with 3 quotes), which is a syntax error. Don't ever paste raw strings into SQL. [Obligatory link](http://bobby-tables.com/) (it also has a .NET section).

Comment: Google "little bobby tables"

Answer (score 0):

I used this instead... its working... thank you

```
            Dim ite As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Items(ResoNo, ItemNo, Qty, Unit, ItemDesc, UnitCost, TotalCost) VALUES('" _
                                              & rn & "'," & it & "," & qt & ",'" & un & "',@id," & uc & "," & tc & ")", dbCon)
            ite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id)
            ite.ExecuteNonQuery()
```